# Convert an xml file into a xslt file in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a xml file and I need to convert it into a xslt file using Java as the programming language.
I know that xslt is used to convert one xml file into another xml or Xhtml or html file.
Please someone let me know if it is possible to generate a xslt file from xml file using java.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert XML to HTML using XSLT in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811581/how-to-convert-xml-to-html-using-xslt-in-java)

Comment: The XSLT file describes a *transformation*, for converting an XML document (*data*) into another form, usually reformatted data (XML) or HTML. How would code *invent* a transformation description (XSLT) from some XML data? What would you expect the invented transformation to do, i.e. if applied to some data (same?, other?), what would the expected *output* be? Or asked a different way: What are you trying to do?

Comment: An XSLT file is an XML file, and of course it is possible to convert one XML file into another using Java, if you have an algorithm that describes the conversion you want to perform. It's even easier to convert one XML file into another using XSLT.